# R rmarkdown ioslides - How to include a segue slide?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

With R rmarkdown using the ioslides_presentation format, if I include css-classes after the heading

```
## MyHeader {.smaller}
```

this actually changes the `<article class='smaller'></article>` element, not the `<slide></slide>` element.

I would like to add a transition/segue slide just like in the ioslides-examples on the web, but I would need to add the classes like so:

```
<slide class='segue dark nobackground'>
```

How can I do this from inside the .Rmd-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a segue slide with a single #, like this

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: ioslides_presentation
---

# In the morning

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed
```

Or you can use a little css to customize the segue slide, for example:

```
.mySegue {
  font-size: 105px;
  line-height: 65px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 60px 120px;
}
```

And then a slide like this:

```
##  {.mySegue}

My Segue Text
```

Comment: Thank you. That was unexpected - still helpful, though!

Comment: No worries, recently got stuck on the same problem!